# how do i convert number starting with decimal to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert number starting with decimal like .15 to 0 rather then 0.15 in javascript.
using ParseInt(value) only work for leading zero numbers like 001 or 0.1.

can anyone provide me good solution ??

Comment: `parseInt(0.15, 10)`

Comment: Use [`Math.floor()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp). Is `.15` a string or already a float?

Comment: i have input field which need to accept whole number with out decimal. 
my code  inside my Jsp for change event  is:
        var value=$(this).val();
  var x=parseInt(value);
  $(this).val(x);
so when i give value like 0.15 it changes to 0,0001 it changes to 1 but if i enter something like .15 then it give NAN error.

Comment: Couldn't you just use Math.round() or do you absolutely need to use parseInt()?

Comment: no ,i am not rounding the value

Answer (score 2):

An `input` value is a **String**! Trying to use `parseInt` on a non-number (string decimal missing integer) will [result in `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) when the parser tries to perform a **string-to-number conversion**:

```
parseInt(".15", 10)         // NaN
```

In that case you need to first convert it to a `Number`:

```
parseInt(Number(".15"), 10) // 0
```

(or using the *Unary* `+`)

```
parseInt( +".15", 10)       // 0
```